# Percona Toolkit Online Schema Change: Possible to add multiple columns all at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema, percona

Does anyone know if it is possible to add multiple columns at one time using Percona's pt-online-schema-change for MySQL? I have tried literally every variant I can think of in order to add multiple columns at one time. It seems like something you should be able to do, but I cannot find any evidence online that you can, nor can I get the syntax to work out. A few of the statements I've attempted are below, to give you an idea what I've tried (username and password edited out, for obvious reasons)

Statement 1:

```
    pt-online-schema-change --print --progress time,5 --max-load Threads_running=1000 
--critical-load Threads_running=10000 --chunk-time 5 --set-vars "innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600" 
--nocheck-plan --execute -h webdb -u xxxx --p xxxx --alter "ADD first_seen datetime NOT NULL 
DEFAULT 0, last_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running"  D=mydata,t=mytable
```

Statement 2:

```
    pt-online-schema-change --print --progress time,5 --max-load Threads_running=1000 
--critical-load Threads_running=10000 --chunk-time 5 --set-vars "innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600" 
--nocheck-plan --execute -h webdb -u xxxx --p xxxx --alter "ADD first_seen datetime NOT NULL 
DEFAULT 0, ADD last_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running"  D=mydata,t=mytable
```

Statement 3:

```
 pt-online-schema-change --print --progress time,5 --max-load Threads_running=1000 
--critical-load Threads_running=10000 --chunk-time 5 --set-vars "innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600" 
--nocheck-plan --execute -h webdb -u xxxx --p xxxx --alter "ADD first_seen datetime NOT NULL 
DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running, ADD last_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running"  
D=mydata,t=mytable
```

And so forth. Basically I've tried every variant I can think of for ADD first_seen datetime NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT 0, ADD last_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running" (moving/removing the after, moving/removing the ADD, moving/removing the comma, etc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) this is possible, just separate the statements with commas. Quoting the `--alter` section of the manual:

> --alter
>
> ```
> type: string
>
> The schema modification, without the ALTER TABLE keywords. You can perform 
> multiple modifications to the table by specifying them with commas. Please 
> refer to the MySQL manual for the syntax of ALTER TABLE.
> ```

In your case this `--alter` should work (assuming the rest of your statement is correct):

```
--alter "ADD first_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, ADD last_seen datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER days_running"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it another shot.... could swear I've already tried that though. Either way, thank you.

Comment: Since which version of pt-osc it work? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `pt-online-schema-change` isn't doing anything special. It just passes the string you enter after prefixing it with some ALTER TABLE command. See the [MySQL Alter Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) syntax